# Chrome's table layout: fixed not working properly after changing the width of the table

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I am inserting multiple tables to a scrollable div with JavaScript. Then insert images to cells. Then I trigger a function that adjusts tables' widths. All the tables have table-layout: fixed. So in FF everything is ok but Chrome renders the first cell of each table wrong - the width is wrong. When I manually toggle the css property table-layout: fixed in developer tools, the first cell's width changes to normal. So I think I have to reapply css rules of tables somehow to get rid of this bug. Is there a way to do this?

This is the function that adjusts tables' widths:

```
function adjustGalleryInnerWidth(){
    var containerWidth = jQuery('.container.table').width(),
        inner = jQuery('#gallery-mod-inner'),
        tables = inner.find('table');        
    inner.width((containerWidth * tables.length) + 150);
    tables.width(containerWidth + 14);
}
```

And here is the table template:

```
<div class="container table">
  <div id="gallery-mod">
      <div id="gallery-mod-inner">
          <table>
              <tr>
                  <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solved the problem by setting table-layout: fixed via jQuery's css method after changing tables width. But I had to remove table-layout: fixed from css file.